# Difference(s) between lang.mixin and declare.safeMixin? Dojotoolkit

Tags: javascript, dojo, mixins

I have already read the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/augmenting_objects/index.html) , even though the author has mentioned the differences , I still don't get it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created two fiddles to show you different cases of how `declare.safeMixin` and `lang.mixin` are working.

Documentation extracted from Dojo code about `declare.safeMixin`:

> This function is used to mix in properties like lang.mixin does, but it skips a constructor property and decorates functions like declare() does.
>   It is meant to be used with classes and objects produced with declare.
>   Functions mixed in with dojo.safeMixin can use this.inherited() like normal methods.
>   This function is used to implement extend() method of a constructor produced with declare().

Documentation extracted from Dojo code about `lang.mixin`:

> All properties, including functions (sometimes termed "methods"), excluding any non-standard extensions found in Object.prototype, are copied/added from sources to dest. sources are processed left to right.
>   The Javascript assignment operator is used to copy/add each property; therefore, by default, mixin executes a so-called "shallow copy" and aggregate types are copied/added by reference.

#### Augmenting a dojo class created with `declare`:

> Working example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hr3nx9yp/1/). You need to open the console to view the logs.

First we declare a dojo class `Person` and then create two instances of this class:

```
var Person = declare(null, {
  name: null,
  message: "foo",
  constructor: function(args) {
    this.name = args.name;
  },
  speak: function() {
    console.log(`   ${this.name} says: '${this.message}'!`);
  }
});


var rob = new Person({ name: "Rob" });
var peter = new Person({ name: "Peter" });
```

If we call the speak method rob and peter will say both `foo`.

Now we modify one instance (`rob`) with `declare.safeMixin` ...

```
  declare.safeMixin(rob, {
    secondMessage: "bar",
    speak: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        console.log(`   ${this.name} says: '${this.secondMessage}'!`);
    }
  });
```

... and the other one (`peter`) with `lang.mixin`.

```
  lang.mixin(peter, {
    secondMessage: "bar",
    speak: function() {
        // this.inherited(arguments); // would cause an error
        console.log(`   ${this.name} says: '${this.secondMessage}'!`);
    }
  });
```

After that, Rob will say two words, because we used `declare.safeMixin`, which annotates that we can use `this.inherited(arguments)` in our **overriden** `speak` method.

Instead of Rob, Peter will say only one word, because we used `lang.mixin`, which completly **overrides** our earliere `speak` method.

**Note**: You can write your code in a such way that `lang.mixin` allows to use `inherited` as well (you need to explicitly name the method you want to call in `this.inherited`):

```
lang.mixin(peter, {
  secondMessage: "bar",
  speak: function() {
      this.inherited('speak', arguments);
      console.log(`   ${this.name} says: '${this.secondMessage}'!`);
  }
});
```

> See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a404p3jk/) for a working example.

#### Augmenting a simple java script object:

> Working example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w84hd853/2/). You need to open the console to view the logs.

First we declare two objects, which have the same property `foo`.

```
  var object= {
    foo: "bar"
  };

  var anotherObject = {
    foo: "bar"
  };
```

Then again we modify both. The `object` instance with `declare.safeMixin` ...

```
  declare.safeMixin(object, {
    baz: 123
  }, {
    baz: 1234
  });
```

... and the `anotherObject` instance with `lang.mixin`.

```
  lang.mixin(anotherObject, {
    baz: 123
  }, {
    baz: 1234
  });
```

Note, that we mixin on both instances, two objects! Now if we try to access the `baz` property of both instances, we will get different results.

The `object` instances `baz` property will return `123`, because `declare.safeMixin` only supports mixin one java script object per method call.

The `anotherObject` instances `baz` property will return `1234`, beacuse `lang.mixin` supports mixin multiple java script objects per method call. Here counts: last one wins.

Hope this makes things a little bit clear.

Comment: This is what is amazing with javascript (and with Dojo) @Sebastian Frey

Comment: well explained @ben